# Create a wordpress under Nodejs app path domain.com/blog

Tags: node.js, wordpress, server, dns, seo

I have a NextJS app (NodeJS) that runs a webapp on domain.com. For SEO purposes I'd like to create a blog with Wordpress that would run under the path domain.com/blog/ . How can I set this up? Is there a way on my DNS server (cloudflare) to say domain.com/blog/ -> go -> Wordpress otherwise -> go -> NodeJS?